# magento 2 admin system message twice

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

Just updated to 2.3.0 and after deploy in admin section i had the following bug:

[image]

How can i solve this?

Comment: did it happen most of the time ? what if after you flush cache and you make some changes did it give you the same result again?

Comment: yep, same result